# Lightning Web Component - passing object between component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to figure out how I can share an object between parent and child components

I've an @api decorated property (objectData) on the child and I include them on in the parent template.

Parent template:

```
<Child object-data={appData}></Child>
```

***appData*** is a property that is filled after a promise was resolved (network call) and is initialized as null. Lets say appData looks like this:

```
{ name: 'Dan' , age: 20 }
```

and now, lets say my child template looks like this:

```
<template if:true={objectData}>
    <div>Name: {objectData.name}</div>
</template>
```

In the above case, my child component never renders.

How can I force the component tree to re-render when the promise is resolved so the data in "appData" will be shared with the child component?

---

Trying again to explain what I'm trying to achieve:
import { LightningElement , api , track} from 'lwc';

```
export default class ServiceHourlyStatus extends LightningElement {

    @api hour;
    @api serviceData;
    @api date;

    get hasIssues() {

        if (this.serviceData && this.serviceData[this.date]) {
            window.console.log(this.serviceData[this.date])
        }

        // more complex logic to be written
        return this.hour === 12;
    }  

}
```

the hasIssues() function should return a boolean if a certain logic is met, what you see now is just a place holder.

the serviceData is a JS object. The keys are a string representation of dates (DD_MM_YYYY) and each one is pointing to another object. This doesn't really matter though. When I'm running a *console.log()* inside the the *hasIssue()* function, I'm getting a proxy object. How can I access these properties? How can I even debug this?

Comment: it should be `c-child`, not `Child`. Is it correct in your actual code?

Comment: this is just a code I wrote here and not my code.
I actually made some progress and my question now is how do I access a property that is decorated with @api from inside the class it's defined?

Comment: Can you pls show the exact code - because you need not really do anything, you can directly access @api properties.

Comment: You can't really access it directly. I will post an example in a minute

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing a similar issue!