# LWC: CallBack list doesn't show on lightning-layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-layouts

I want to make a LWC which input keywords and show the results on list using lightning-layout & lightning-layout-item. And I want to make it that doesn't depend on SObjects.

Now, I have a problem the list. it inputs any keywords doesn't show anything.
html is below;

```
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
            <lightning-input
                type="search" label=""
                name="search-key"
                placeholder="Input Name for Search"
                onchange={handleSearchKeyChanged} 
                value={searchKey}>
            </lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>

    <div class="slds-m-around_small">
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows="true" draggable="true">
            <template if:true={searchResult} for:each={searchResult} for:item="row" key={row.id}>
                <lightning-layout-item key={row.id}>
                    <span>{row.name}, {row.detail}, {row.lastUpdate}</span>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout>
    </div>
```

and here is JS;

```
searchKey = '';
searchedResult = {};

handleSearchKeyChanged(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(this.delayTimeout);
    const searchKey = e.target.value;
    this.delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchKey = searchKey;
    }, DELAY);
}

@wire(getSearchedList, {searchKey: '$searchKey', selectSObj: '$selectedSObj'})
getSearchedListResult({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        this.searchedResult = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('>>> searchResult: ', this.searchedResult);
            
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
};
```

console.log in getSearchedListResult, it shows data.
It worked when I use lightning-datatable, but it can't use for my reason.

I think it's similler question is here but it looks unresolved:
[Lightning Web Component - passing object between component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274413/lightning-web-component-passing-object-between-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your markup, you use `searchResult`, but in your JS, you use `searchedResult`. This is likely what's causing your problem.

Also, your `searchResult` should be an array, not an object:

```
searchResult = []; // not {};
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox ! I didn't find this typo... Now, it works!